# How do I cancel and roll back part of a workflow

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have a very long running workflow that moves video files around between video processing devices and then reports the files state to a database which is used to drive a UI

At times the users press a button on the UI to "Accept" a file into a video storage server.  This involves copying a file from one server to another.]

They have asked if this activity can be cancelled.

I've looked at the wf4 documentation and I can't see a way to roll back part of a workflow.

Is this possible and what technique should I use.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to rollback? In other words what exactly are you doing that you want to undo?

Comment: In this scenario I want to go from a state where the file is copying back to the previous state where the workflow is waiting for the user to press the Accept button.  Once the users have this they will ( I'm sure) ask for a Cancel ability in many of the tasks the workflow does ( writing to xml files, producing PDF reports) so I really want to know if I can roll back to an earlier part of a workflow and undo what was done.

Comment: Are you currently using the `StateMachine` or `FlowChart`?

Comment: I'm using FlowChart although I can switch if state machine is better as I moving from version 1 to version 2 of the product

Comment: Oh no, one isn't really better than the other here, I just wanted to know what you were currently using. Alright, let me see if I can get you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's first say that the processing of "rolling back" what was already uploaded will have to be done by hand, so where ever you're storing those chunks you'll need to clean up by hand when they cancel.

Now, on to the workflow itself, in my opinion you could setup your `FlowChart` like this:

[image: FlowChart]

[image: Process Loop Part 1]

[image: Process Loop Part 2]

Alright so let's break down this workflow. The entire service should be correlated on some client key so that way you can start the service with `Start` once per client to keep the startup costs down.

Next, when said client wants to start a transfer you'll call `BeginTransfer` which will move into the transfer loop. The transfer loop is setup so that you can cancel between chunks if necessary by calling `CancelTransfer`.

That same branch, in this model, is used to **finish** the transfer as well because it gets out of the loop, so when your done transferring chunks just call `CancelTransfer` (if you don't like that just setup a different branch that looks exactly the same).

Finally, when you're in the process loop, you can `SoftExit` the entire workflow and shut it down so that you can kill it softly if there is necessary maintenance **or** when the client is finished with its connection it needs to call `SoftExit` to dispose of it.

Comment: Gosh, that's quite comprehensive, thanks.  I think I've got it. I'll make a version to see

Answer (score 2):

The are two basic inbuild activities for reverting work.

1. The TransactionScope for ACID transaction
2. The Compensable activity for long running work.

With the Compensable activity you add activities to the compensation handler to undo work previously done. The Compensate activity can be used to trigger compensation. If there is no compensation you will get the confirmation handler either at the end of the workflow automatically or when you use the Conform activity.

See [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) in .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx) by Matt Milner for more details.

Comment: With the `Compensable` activity, can it roll back changes made to objects as well? I ask because if I'm not mistaken the `TransactionScope` activity only manages entering transactions for things that implement the .NET transaction model (e.g. `MSMQ` or `SqlConnection`)

Comment: With a Compensable activity you are responsible for undoing the changes. There is no automatic rollback as with the TransactionScope activity. As a result you can rollback anything you want to as long as you can write the code to do so.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure. So when I stated that to "roll back" you're on your own I was right there -- except for some type of system that manages transactions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I totally understand your scenario but I think you would need to run your transfer process on an asynchronous thread, that from time to time check a "cancel" variable to perform a rollback. This variable can be modified on the main thread on your UI.

Of course, this will allow you to cancel between transfers, not in the midle on one single transfer.

Comment: As I copy in chunks (I use FTP for all transfers) it seems to me that I can cancel mid transfer.  It's a good answer but I would like to know if I can cancel and roll back part of a workflow